# Amazon EC2- Security groups and Whitelisting IPs

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've recently created an Amazon EC2 instance. We have internal business pages that will be hosted on this instance, so it should be secured to where only internal members of the project team can access it. I'm familiar with opening HTTP access to only specific IPs. This works fine, however, sometimes members connect from many different places besides their home and office, so the IP is always changing. Is it possible to restrict access by using a Gemalto MFA token, or another means besides IP so we dont have to whitelist an IP address each time we connect to it for the first time?

Thanks in advance for any solutions you are able to present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not.. I think your best way to solve this problem is by setting up a VPN in the office and have people VPN into the office and tunnel traffic for that subnet through the office or just setup a full tunnel.